# Speeding up Crystal Reports with multiple databases

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm working on a series of reports that link various tables within several databases. The resulting recordset returned to Crystal can be millions of records, so generating a single report can take up to an hour or more. Looking at options of speeding up data retrieval, it seems SQL expressions would be ideal so that the database server can do the filtering and return just what Crystal needs, rather than everything. However, it appears Crystal won't do SQL expressions when more than one database is involved.

The only solution I can think of is to create a view for each report. There are no parameters used for filtering, but each report is unqiue in its record selection. Before undertaking this, I wanted to see if there are any other options for speeding up report generation in this situation.

Crystal Reports 2010 with a SQL Server 2008 backend.

Comment: Are all of the databases SQL Server?  Have you considered linked servers?

Comment: All SQL Server, already linked, which I'd use to create the views.